# How to determine the range of a angle measure?

Tags: triangles

In $\Delta$ $KLM$, $KL=20$ $LM=13$ m$\angle K$$=40$. What is the range for angle $M$'s measure? Something like between $90^{\circ}$ and $180^{\circ}$.

[image]

Comment: I think it's safe enough to say angle $M$ is in the range between $0$ and $180$ degrees. Actually there are precisely two possible values, of which one is less than $90$ degrees and the other is greater than $90$ degrees. This question is far too vague in its current wording.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the law of sine, then find the value exact of angle measure

$$\frac{\sin{(M)}}{20}=\frac{\sin{(K)}}{13}$$

Comment: Without the calculation?

Comment: you can use calculator? or not

Comment: When the given condition is in 'ASS' situation, there could be TWO possible answers for M. See my answer in problem no. 690645. In your case, YES there are two.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the altitude $LS$ of the isoceles triangle $\triangle M_1LM_2$.

Then $LS=13\sin\phi$. On the other hand, since $\sin K=\frac{LS}{KL}$ we have $\sin 40^{\circ}=\frac{13\sin\phi}{20}$. Hence, $\sin\phi=\frac{20\sin40^{\circ}}{13}\approx 0.9889$ and $\phi\approx 81.4568^{\circ}$ (the acute angle solution).

The obtuse angle solution is $180^{\circ}-\phi\approx 98.5432^{\circ}.$